# How can I restart a thread in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, arduino

I`m troubling with something here, I don't know if someone can light me up a little bit.

I have a method, that I call on a AsyncTask class on the onPostExecute callback:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!ConnectSuccess)
        {
            msg("Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again.");
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            msg("Connected.");
            isBtConnected = true;
            beginListenForData();
        }
        progress.dismiss();
    }
```

it start a thread (in this case is giving me some information from my arduino):

```
private void beginListenForData()
{
    Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Creating handler");
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //super.handleMessage(msg);
            if(msg.what == ConnectedThread.RESPONSE_MESSAGE){
                String txt = (String)msg.obj;
                if(myLabel.getText().toString().length() >= 30){
                    myLabel.setText("");
                    myLabel.append(txt);
                }else{
                    myLabel.append("\n" + txt);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Creating and running Thread");
    btt = new ConnectedThread(btSocket,mHandler);
    btt.start();
}
```

This is my code from the run method:

```
    public void run(){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;
    write("PIN".toString().getBytes());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mmInStream));
    Log.i("[THREAD-CT]","Starting thread");
    while(true){
        try{
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            String resp = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
            //String resp = br.readLine();
            //Transfer these data to the UI thread
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = RESPONSE_MESSAGE;
            msg.obj = resp;
            uih.sendMessage(msg);
        }catch(IOException e){
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.i("[THREAD-CT]","While loop ended");
}
```

The problem is that when I send an information to my arduino (pressing a button). This is my code for write:

```
    public void write(byte[] bytes){
    try{
        Log.i("[THREAD-CT]", "Writting bytes");
        mmOutStream.write(bytes);

    }catch(IOException e){}
}
```

It stopped listening what I start at the beginning. It didn´t go to the run method again. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095207/how-to-restart-a-thread-in-android) answer but i´m not quite sure how to implement async task here.

Comment: Why is this tagged `arduino`?  I see no arduino code as per the tag requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the problem was not in my android code but in my arduino code. It seems that after I send the information, my arduino stop sending too. I already fix this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use an async task whose onPostExecute() can runOnUiThread(). This will keep it listening. See the sample code of such an async task here:

```
private class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            }
        });
    }
}
```